# Python script takes longer as it runs

Tags: python, performance, file

I have a Python script that imports some log data into a `StringIO` object and then reads the data in that, line by line, and enters them into a DB table. The script takes considerably longer after some iteration. To explain, it takes ~1.6 seconds to run through 1500 logs, and ~1m16s to run through 3500 logs and then 20 second for 1100 logs!

My script is laid out as follows:

```
for dir in dirlist:
    file = StringIO.StringIO(...output from some system command to get logs...)
    for line in file:
        ctr+=1
        ...
        do some regex matches and replacements
        ...
        cursor.insert(..."insert query"...)
        if ctr >= 1000:
            conn.commit() # commit once every 1000 transactions
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that the performance drops at the database level. If you stop and restart the script every 1000 items, does the performance still drop?

Comment: I agree. But without the actual code details inside 'do some regex matches and replacements', it leaves an element of doubt!

Comment: Until now I have tried running the script at one go. I'll try running it against each directory, one at a time and see how that performs

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the regexes. because the same set of regex matches are performed for the first set of loops too.

Answer (score 1):

Use cProfile to profile your script and find out where the time is actually spent. It is not usually helpful to just guess where the time is spent without any details. Profiling will tell you whether the performance issue is with some regex matching stuff or the insert query.